# Linking 2 columns of one table to 1 column of other in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I am a Crystal Reports Novice. Lets consider two tables A and B.

Table A

```
A1  A2
```

Table B

```
B1  B2  B3
```

Basically I am joining A and B on A1(can be NULL) and B1 to get B3.
Since we added a new functionality table A becomes -
A1,A2,A3

So now If A1 is Null A3 should join to B1 to get B3.

I am having hard time accommodating this change in "Links" in Database Expert in Crystal Reports.

I tried links both A1 and A3 to B1 to get B3 but it didn't work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

FYI - I believe this how it looks in SQL -

```
SELECT 
    B.B3 
FROM 
    B 
        INNER JOIN A     ON B.B1 = COALESCE(A.A1,A.A3) 
;
```

Thanks again.

Comment: Can you include sample data for each of the tables, and show what the output would be?

Comment: And why I am not able to format code blocks ?

Comment: @destination-data
Table A - A1 A2 A3 1 Honda Toyota 3 Table B - B1 B2 B3 1 Autonation Civic 3 Earnhardt Camry SELECT B.B3 FROM B INNER JOIN A ON B.B1 = COALESCE(A.A1,A.A3) ; B3 Civic Camry

Comment: Here's [a link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), that shows how formatting works on SO.  To format your code prefix each line with 4 blank spaces, or use the backtick to delimit inline code (example:  `SELECT Something FROM Somewhere`).

Answer (score 0):

you can do using CASE STATEMENT

```
SELECT B.B3
FROM A,B
WHERE
  B.B1=CASE 
       WHEN A.A1 IS NULL THEN A.A3
       ELSE A.A1
       END
```

Comment: I want to know how to do that in Crystal Reports Database Expert when I link tables